# Add indentation after performing word-break using css

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to add indentation to the text that moves to new line after word-break. Currently, it doesn't even consider the padding-left given to the parent object and is displayed on the extreme left side after word break.

[image]
In the image above, you can see that permission line is performing word break and 0... is sticking on the left side. I would like it to display below the first alphabet of P or after that.

```
  position: relative;
  left: 76%;
  top: -755px;
  width: 22%;
  height: 508px;
  color:rgb(3, 3, 3);
  background-color: #bdddf0;
  z-index: 10;
  border-style: groove;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 630px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 15px;
  h2 {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
```

.SummaryPanel is the className of parent element.
How should I control both word-wrap and indentation ? Is it possible to control it ?

Comment: Can you post all your code and post a [MCVE]? ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) is great for react)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add text-indent property your summarypanel class like below

```
    padding-left: 2em;
    text-indent: -2em;
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9phwnxby/1/

Hope it helps